# Agrupar JSON utilizando reduce() do javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Existe alguma maneira de agrupar um Json utilizando o método `Reduce()` do Javascript, conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
contas = [{id: 1, descricao: "AGUA", valor: 100, juros: 5},
          {id: 1, descricao: "AGUA", valor: 100, juros: 5},
          {id: 2, descricao: "LUZ", valor: 150, juros: 10},
          {id: 2, descricao: "LUZ", valor: 150, juros: 10}];
```

que retorne da seguinte forma:

```
contas = [{id:1, descricao: "AGUA", valor: 200, juros: 10},
          {id:2, descricao: "LUZ", valor: 300, juros: 20}];
```

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podemos utilizar o `reduce` iniciando com um acumulador de array vazio e ir adicionando ao acumulador elementos que tenham o `id` diferente. Sempre que encontramos um `id` igual somamos o `valor` e os `juros` ao que já la está.

Exemplo:

```js
contas = [{id: 1, descricao: "AGUA", valor: 100, juros: 5},
          {id: 1, descricao: "AGUA", valor: 100, juros: 5},
          {id: 2, descricao: "LUZ", valor: 150, juros: 10},
          {id: 2, descricao: "LUZ", valor: 150, juros: 10}];
   
   
var total = contas.reduce(function (acumulador, valor){
  //achar o indice do objeto no acumulador através do id
  var indice = acumulador.map((o) => o.id).indexOf(valor.id); 
  
  if (indice == -1){ //se não existe no acumulador adiciona o objeto corrente
    acumulador.push(valor);
  }
  else { //se já existe aumenta o valor e os juros
    acumulador[indice].valor += valor.valor;
    acumulador[indice].juros += valor.juros;

  }
  
  return acumulador; 

}, []); //iniciar o acumulador com array vazio
          

console.log(total);
```

Comment: Perfeito! Era isso mesmo que eu precisava, obrigado!