# Somar valores de diferentes índices do JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Tenho uma API que um trecho dela retorna o seguinte array, e para cada index tem um objeto `slas` que traz todas as transportadoras:

```
[
  {
    "itemIndex": 0,
    "selectedSla": "Expressa",
    "selectedDeliveryChannel": "delivery",
    "slas": [
      {
        "name": "Expressa",
        "shippingEstimate": "2bd",
        "price": 1390
      },
      {
        "name": "SEDEX",
        "shippingEstimate": "2bd",
        "price": 1990
      },
      {
        "name": "Retira em SÃO PAULO (1936769)",
        "shippingEstimate": "1bd",
        "price": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "itemIndex": 1,
    "selectedSla": "Expressa",
    "selectedDeliveryChannel": "delivery",
    "slas": [
      {
        "name": "Expressa",
        "shippingEstimate": "2bd",
        "price": 1390
      },
      {
        "name": "SEDEX",
        "shippingEstimate": "2bd",
        "price": 1990
      },
      {
        "name": "Retira em SÃO PAULO (1936769)",
        "shippingEstimate": "1bd",
        "price": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Eu queria somar o valor total de cada transportadora.

Exemplo:

```
0: EXPRESSA 13,90 + 1: EXPRESSA 13,90

0: SEDEX 19,90 + 1: SEDEX 13,90
```

Comment: Poderia postar o retorno exato da api, como postou não está válido.

Comment: @LeAndrade o json é muito extenso por isso resumi ele no trecho que referente.

Comment: Do jeito como está não tem como formar uma resposta correta, pois, não tem como saber a  estrutura do json.

Comment: @LeAndrade Desculpe, agora esta validado o json.

Comment: Se o objetivo é agrupar pelo `slas` já existem perguntas sobre  isso

Comment: @Isac Não achei nada similar, poderia informar qual perguntas são?!

Comment: Como exemplo pode olhar para [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/221342/agrupar-json-utilizando-reduce-do-javascript) ou [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/342198/l%c3%b3gica-para-agrupar-dados-em-array-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dá para fazer o que quer utilizando os métodos [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) e [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) do seguinte modo:

```js
let retorno = [
  {
    "itemIndex": 0,
    "selectedSla": "Expressa",
    "selectedDeliveryChannel": "delivery",
    "slas": [
      {
        "name": "Expressa",
        "shippingEstimate": "2bd",
        "price": 1390
      },
      {
        "name": "SEDEX",
        "shippingEstimate": "2bd",
        "price": 1990
      },
      {
        "name": "Retira em SÃO PAULO (1936769)",
        "shippingEstimate": "1bd",
        "price": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "itemIndex": 1,
    "selectedSla": "Expressa",
    "selectedDeliveryChannel": "delivery",
    "slas": [
      {
        "name": "Expressa",
        "shippingEstimate": "2bd",
        "price": 1390
      },
      {
        "name": "SEDEX",
        "shippingEstimate": "2bd",
        "price": 1990
      },
      {
        "name": "Retira em SÃO PAULO (1936769)",
        "shippingEstimate": "1bd",
        "price": 0
      }
    ]
  }
];

let expressa = [];        // arrays que serão guardados os objetos similares
let sedex = [];
let retira = [];

let dados = retorno.map(x => x.slas);          // mapeia os objetos que queremos

expressa = dados.map(x => x[0]);              // insere os objetos similares no array
sedex = dados.map(x => x[1]);
retira = dados.map(x => x[2]);

let valorExpressa = expressa.reduce((a,b) => {   // faz a soma dos valores
  return a + b.price;
},0);

let valorSedex = sedex.reduce((a,b) => {
  return a + b.price;
},0);

let valorRetira = retira.reduce((a,b) => {
  return a + b.price;
},0);

console.log('Valor Expressa: ', valorExpressa);
console.log('Valor SEDEX: ', valorSedex);
console.log('Valor Retira: ', valorRetira);
```

Comment: No caso do array das transportadoras, em algumas condições será 2 e outra 3.
E futuramente terá mais, como deixar isso dinâmico?

Comment: Como assim? Não entendi.

Comment: você criou um array pra cada transportadora, ali no caso estão 3 definidas como deixar isso dinamico, ao invés de deixar manual, entendeu?

Comment: Então, esses arrays são os recipientes para cada transportadora, eu preciso criar um array para cada um, se não, não consigo fazer a soma dos valores de cada uma.

Comment: Ao invés de criar um array pra cada transportadora, eu vou tirar um único com todas e o valor já somado, assim fica mais fácil de trabalhar e dinâmico.

Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda!

Comment: Sim, pode ser tbm, é que para dar uma reposta mais conclusiva, precisaria ter uma visão maior de como chegariam esses dados, foi uma maneira que vi de fazer no momento, mas, se conseguiu resolver melhor. Sucesso aí man!

Answer (score 1):

Cheguei em uma *solução* "*[dinâmica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/399531/somar-valores-de-diferentes-%c3%adndices-do-json/401360#comment786128_399548)*" utilizando somente [métodos de iteração](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Iteration_methods) do protótipo do [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

```js
const data = [{
  itemIndex: 0,
  selectedSla: 'Expressa',
  selectedDeliveryChannel: 'delivery',
  slas: [
    { name: 'Expressa', shippingEstimate: '2bd', price: 1390 },
    { name: 'SEDEX', shippingEstimate: '2bd', price: 1990 },
    { name: 'Retira em SÃO PAULO (1936769)', shippingEstimate: '1bd', price: 0 }
  ]
}, {
  itemIndex: 1,
  selectedSla: 'Expressa',
  selectedDeliveryChannel: 'delivery',
  slas: [
    { name: 'Expressa', shippingEstimate: '2bd', price: 1390 },
    { name: 'SEDEX', shippingEstimate: '2bd', price: 1990 },
    { name: 'Retira em SÃO PAULO (1936769)', shippingEstimate: '1bd', price: 0 }
  ]
}];

function getSumFrom(list) {
  return list
    .map((arr) => arr.slas)
    .flat(1) // Juntamos todos os arrays de objetos em um único array de objetos.
    .reduce((acc, current) => {
      const name = current.name;
      const price = current.price;

      // Basicamente, estamos adicionando ao acumulador (`acc`)
      // o nome da empresa. Para isso, estamos somando o valor do
      // preço da iteração atual ao valor já existente.
      //
      // Se o valor existente ainda não existir, consideramos que
      // ele seja zero.
      // (`acc[name] || 0` diz: se `acc[name]` for falsey, assuma zero).
      acc[name] = (acc[name] || 0) + price;
      return acc;
    }, {});
}

console.log(getSumFrom(data));
```

Tentei não deixar o código muito complexo no excerto acima para facilitar a leitura do código para quem está iniciando na linguagem. Mas se você já está mergulhando mais fundo no JavaScript, o código acima pode ser reduzido:

```js
const data = [{
  itemIndex: 0,
  selectedSla: 'Expressa',
  selectedDeliveryChannel: 'delivery',
  slas: [
    { name: 'Expressa', shippingEstimate: '2bd', price: 1390 },
    { name: 'SEDEX', shippingEstimate: '2bd', price: 1990 },
    { name: 'Retira em SÃO PAULO (1936769)', shippingEstimate: '1bd', price: 0 }
  ]
}, {
  itemIndex: 1,
  selectedSla: 'Expressa',
  selectedDeliveryChannel: 'delivery',
  slas: [
    { name: 'Expressa', shippingEstimate: '2bd', price: 1390 },
    { name: 'SEDEX', shippingEstimate: '2bd', price: 1990 },
    { name: 'Retira em SÃO PAULO (1936769)', shippingEstimate: '1bd', price: 0 }
  ]
}];

function getSumFrom(list) {
  return list
    .flatMap(({ slas }) => slas)
    .reduce(
      (acc, { name, price }) => ({
        ...acc,
        [name]: (acc[name] || 0) + price
      }),
      {}
    );
}

console.log(getSumFrom(data));
```

Eu pessoalmente prefiro essa segunda abordagem, mas isso é pessoal. :)